2024 iBeacon BLE - Xcode 15.4 iOS iBeacon app advertising sets and beacon monitoring issue
I developed iOS app that is using startMonitoring(for: region) method to detect region entry and exit events via didEnterRegion and didExitRegion delegate methods.
Region monitoring worked for years and stopped working recently.

Now my app "magically" starts working for few minutes when I open apps that are used to manage beacons(set UUID, major , minor - I am using KBeacon and FeasyBeacon iOS apps)
If my app were faulty, it would NOT start working just by opening the Kbeacomn or FeasyBeacon apps. If my code were incorrect, the app would NEVER work until the code is fixed.
Apple support states that startMonitoring still works, despite the fact that it is Deprecated,and they agree that if my app was broken it would not start working when I open beacon management apps

That leaves the beacons(my app worked with these same beacons for years). Now I am using multiple apps to make sure beacons are advertising proper iBeacon signal such as Beacon Scope, BT Inspector, LightBlue,and it seems all beacons are only in iBeacon mode, they advertise UUID, major , minor, they only say iBeacon for format. I did not update beacon firmware
Now Apple Tech support says

that the fact that KBeacon/FeasyBeacon apps are able to see the beacons and have the information means that the beacons are not in iBeacon mode.
iBeacon is required to only send ADV_NONCONN_IND packets, which will instruct anyone scanning to not send a SCAN_REQ (Scan Request).
A Scan Request is a specific BLE command, and by definition of the iBeacon spec, the beacon is required to be non-scannable.
Also they say the issue might be in that these are dual beacons that can advertise ibeacon or other formats - the fact that kBeacon is able to see the advertising from the beacons despite not using CoreLocation means that either the beacons are not advertising as iBeacon until kBeacon is launched, or they are advertising in such a way that the iBeacon advertising is not compliant enough to be recognized.

My Questions

Does anyone know / have any idea why my app starts detecting regions only after I open KBeacon or FeasyBeacon apps? These beacon apps sendScan Request,a nd beacons send Scan response, and it seems iOS is able to see feacons only after beacons send Scan Response back, but iOS should be able to see beacons during nornal scan
Any recommendation on "sniffer" apps that could help me figure out sniffer log and what's being advertised, as this is the only sure way to figure out what is going on with KBeacon/FeasyBeacon apps, iOS and iBeacon beacons.
What does it mean that iBeacon should be non-scannable?
Can anyone point me to books / resources on BLE and iBeacon specification?

Thank you

There is brilliant answer below, but I just wanted to share some resources about BLE , so that any iOS developer that knows his code is correct and finds himself in the world of BLE devices and all of their details and technical specifications can use them to better understand and fix their app, even if that means fixing beacon settings: 1) https://www.bluetooth.com/
2) Apple Accessory Guidelines has a BLE section: https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf
3) https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/
4) https://punchthrough.com/resources/

I suspect the reason your app detects only when other apps are scanning is because those apps start unfiltered BLE scans.  The scans started by region monitoring APIs are filtered, meaning the exact iBeacon prefix must match not for bit or there will be no detection.  If your beacon transmitter prefix is malformed by a single bit, it may not match the filter, but it might still pass programmatic decoding after an unfiltered scan.  This may explain the symptoms you see.
A few tips:

To eliminate issues with the hardware beacon you are testing, use an off-the-shelf beacon transmitter like BeaconScope for iOS or Android to advertise an iBeacon.  Does your app pick it up without running another app at the same time?  If so, this points to a problem with your hardware beacon.

You can see the exact bytes your hardware beacon is advertising by using the Nordic NRF Connect app for Android, and using it to scan your beacon.  If you post the bytesp it reads, we may be able to say more.

The ADV_NONCONN_IND is just a flag field in the advertisement that works as Apple support said.  Scan responses are not needed to detect iBeacon on any platform, so I highly doubt that is the problem.  But the above test will help track this down on the off chance that it is.

The Apple iBeacon specification is proprietary, and Apple only shares it with people who register with Apple and  sign a nondisclosure agreement with them.  Fortunately it is super simple to reverse engineer, which is exactly what I did before Apple got mad and made my former boss take down my blog post about it: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2013/10/01/reverse-engineering-the-ibeacon-profile

If you really want a book, I co-authored this one.  It's several years old, but things have not changed that much.


By the way, I have also seen some of my old apps doing Bluetooth scanning work differently depending on whether I compiled them with a very old Xcode version or the lastest version.  This may explain part of what you are seeing -- it is unclear if you are re-compiling the old app or using it in original binary form.

Thank you David, brilliant answer as always! I will follow your guidelines, and if I find something such as bytes that beacons advertise, I will try beacon transmitter, and thanks for the resources! This is very valueable for any iOS developer that is debugging Beacon app and has to understand about how BLE works, about advertising, packages, radio channels, formats and specifications etc. Thank you!
